# Jsp download file size

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, download

We are running tomcat, and we are generating pdf files on the fly.  I do not have the file size before hand, so I cannot direcly link to a file on the server.  So I directly send the output.

```
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
```

And then I directly output to this OutputStream.

The only problem is that the receiver does not get the filesize, so they do not know how long the download will take.  Is there a way to tell the response how large the file is?

**EDIT**
  I do know the filesize, I just cant tell the STREAM how big the file is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response object should have a [setContentLength](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength(int)) method:

```
// Assumes response is a ServletResponse
response.setContentLength(sizeHere);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The OP updated the question and said he knows the file size, just doesn't know how to specify that in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the PDF byte stream to a file or in a byte array calculate its size, set the size and write it to the output stream.

Comment: I do have the pdf as a file.  I need to tell the STREAM how big the file is.

Comment: That's very inefficient, especially for large PDF files, and if notifying users of the remaining download time is a concern, chances are the file is large.

Comment: Well, it is just a pdf that can be from 2-56MB.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you're ansering the qustion your self:
quote:
I do not have the file size before hand, so I directly send the output.

If you don't have the size you cant send it....

Comment: the size is not static, but I do know it when i send the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate the PDF file in to temp file system , or ram-base file system or memory-map file on the fly. then you can get the file size.

response.setContentType("application/force-download");
response.setContentLength(sizeHere);
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();

Comment: I have the filesize. See my Edit.